# Помогите оптимизировать запрос db2

Tags: sql, db2

Помогите оптимизировать запрос. Выглядит он монстрообразно.

```
select distinct  PUBLSEQ from PUBLCOVER P
      WHERE EXISTS
      ( SELECT * FROM PUBLCOVER A, XCOVERAREA B, XPRODCODEDICT C
        WHERE A.PUBLSEQ = P.PUBLSEQ
        AND A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
        AND A.COVAREA = B.COVAREA
        AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
        AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE = C.PRODCODE
        AND C.STATUS = 'A'
        AND A.COVAREA = 1823
        )
      AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT * FROM PUBLCOVER A, XCOVERAREA B, XPRODCODEDICT C
        WHERE A.PUBLSEQ = P.PUBLSEQ
        AND A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
        AND A.COVAREA = B.COVAREA
        AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
        AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE = C.PRODCODE
        AND C.STATUS = 'A'
        AND A.COVAREA NOT IN (1823, 34)
        )
```

Очень бы хотелось избавиться от **EXISTS** или **NOT EXISTS**, оставив один из них.

Comment: Дайте знать - помогли ли Вам ответы или все равно что-то не так?

Answer (score 1):

Давайте попробуем так:

```
WITH SEQAREA AS 
  (
  SELECT DISTINCT A.PUBLSEQ, A.COVAREA 
  FROM PUBLCOVER A
    JOIN XCOVERAREA B ON B.COVAREA = A.COVAREA
    JOIN XPRODCODEDICT C ON C.PRODCODE = B.COVAREA_PRODCODE
  WHERE
    A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y' AND        
    B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL AND 
    C.STATUS = 'A'
  )
SELECT DISTINCT SA1.SEQ
FROM SEQAREA SA1
 LEFT JOIN SEQAREA SA2 ON SA1.SEQ = SA2.SEQ and SA2.AREA NOT IN (1823, 34) 
WHERE SA2.SEQ IS NULL AND SA1.AREA = 1823
```

Сначала мы соединим все участвующие таблицы, чтобы получить одну широкую, виртуальную таблицу и выберем из нее все уникальные пары `publseq` и `covarea`. Сделаем это внутри `cte` (конструкция `with`). 
Затем соединим получившиеся результаты сами с собой так, чтобы с одной стороны были все записи, а с другой только те, у которых `area` не равна 1823 или 34.
Тогда нужные нам записи будут иметь справа значения `null`. Используя это знание и применяя дополнительный фильтр, чтобы откинуть записи с `area` равной 34 мы получим то, что нам нужно.
Судя по документации `db2` должен материализовать запрос в конструкции `with` так, что двойное обращение к этому запросу просканирует таблицы только один раз.

Answer (score 0):

думаю будет так

```
 select distinct PUBLSEQ from PUBLCOVER P
  WHERE EXISTS
  ( 
   SELECT count(*) cou, A.COVAREA      
      FROM PUBLCOVER A, XCOVERAREA B, XPRODCODEDICT C
     WHERE A.PUBLSEQ = P.PUBLSEQ
       AND A.COVER_STATUS = 'Y'
       AND A.COVAREA = B.COVAREA
       AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE IS NOT NULL
       AND B.COVAREA_PRODCODE = C.PRODCODE
       AND C.STATUS = 'A'
       AND A.COVAREA IN (1823, 34)
     GROUP BY A.COVAREA
    HAVING (A.COVAREA = 1823 AND cou > 0)
       AND (A.COVAREA = 34   AND cou = 0)
    )
```

Comment: к сожалению запрос не выполняется из-за условий cou > 0 и cou = 0

Comment: @Telal какую ошибку дал? по условиям в задаче номер 1823 должен быть а 34 не должен, не так ли?

Comment: @Saidolim Вы сначала отбираете все записи у которых `covarea` не равна 1823 или 34, затем группируете по `covarea`, а потом выбираете из того, что получилось записи, у которых `covarea` равна 1823. Но таких записей не будет потому, что вы их отфильтровали в самом начале. Как то [так](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48aa56/2).

Comment: @ApInvent согласен, не заметил что слово `NOT` не должно быть. исправил, спасибо